# DataGrid to excel not showing automatic gridlines

Tags: c#, excel, datagrid, ashx

Wondering if anyone can assist. I have an .ashx file which creates an excel document which is populated with a C# DataGrid. This all works well the only problem is when I open the excel document the automatic gridlines are turned off. Is there a way to enable them?

Thanks in advance,
Air

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            response.Clear();
            response.Charset = "";
            response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"dataImportTemplate.xls\"");
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid dg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
                    dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    dg.ShowHeader = false;
                    dg.DataBind();                    
                    dg.RenderControl(htw);
                    response.Write(sw.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please show us the code that creates excel document

Comment: Hi, I've added the code into the original post

Comment: Try to set the datagrid's BorderColor, BorderStyle & BorderWidth before you pass it to response.write

Comment: Hi, tried that and it only set the borders on the datagrid. It did not enable the automatic grid lines on the excel document :(

Answer (score 0):

If you export to a csv it keeps the gridlines.
This is a pretty simple workaround that a lot of people opt to use.

See similear post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376204/export-gridview-to-excel-without-losing-grid-lines-in-excel)

That post includes a helper function that supposedly can add the gridlines to your export.

Hope this helps.