# Export Gridview to an existing Excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export GridView to Excel without losing grid lines in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376204/export-gridview-to-excel-without-losing-grid-lines-in-excel)

Is there a way to export a Gridview to an existing excel file?
I have formated the excel file and now I wish to populate it with the gridview or the datatable?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately you have provided almost no information which makes it impossible for us to help you. Please expand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no.